# Directed curvature of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

So I have this following exercise

Consider the curve given by the graph of the sine function $t \rightarrow (t,\sin(t))$. Determine the directed curvature at each point of this curve.

Supposing that directed curvatue and oriented curvature is the same thing there is a definition saying that oriented curvature is given by the identity

$$T'(t_0)=\left(\kappa_{\alpha}(t_0) \ \cdot \parallel\alpha'(t_0)\parallel \right)N(t_0)$$

If the turning angle of the curve $\theta(t)$ is known, then $\kappa_{\alpha}(t)= \displaystyle\frac{\theta'(t)}{\parallel \alpha'(t) \parallel}$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Help you do what? Do the calculations! But, be careful. In your definition, $N$ is not the principal normal vector, but rather a unit vector perpendicular to $T$ so that $T,N$ make a right-handed frame at each point.

Comment: Okay so for a curve parametrized by arc length $\parallel \alpha'(t) \parallel=1$ then $T'(t_0)=\kappa_{\alpha}(t_0)N(t_0)$ and $T'(t)=\alpha''(t)$. Then I take the derivative $\alpha'(t)=(1,\cos (t))$ and $\alpha''(t)=(0,-\sin (t))$. Hereafter I am stuck.

Comment: I found out how to do it now